# How do I clear search results in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, markers

In Eclipse, a file search for a text pattern results in a yellow arrow at the far left margin for each line containing a match. How can I clear these markers? They obscure any breakpoints I wish to place at those lines.

[image]

Comment: It sometimes helps if you put your version of eclipse down in the question.

Comment: I would'veJames, but I've seen this in so many different versions I thought it was standard in all versions. Next time I'll do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open the search view: Window -> Show view -> Other -> General -> Search

Click the "clear all" button (it looks like 2 crosses),

Just to add, on mouse over of the two crosses, tool tip reads as `Remove All Matches`, and to make it more clear[image],